# Adding events to table_calendar

Tags: flutter, calendar

I am very new to flutter/Dart programming and am confused by the code below. I didn't write the code but I would like to use it to display event markers on the calendar grid of the table_calendar plugin.

```
class calEvent {
  final String title;

  const calEvent(this.title);

  @override
  String toString() => title;
}

/// Example events.
///
/// Using a [LinkedHashMap] is highly recommended if you decide to use a map.
final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<calEvent>>(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(_kEventSource);
**<<<<<<  I think FirestoreService().getEvent() would go here but I don't know how to add it or convert from Stream<List<Event>> to LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<calEvent>>  >>>>>>**
final _kEventSource = Map.fromIterable(List.generate(50, (index) => index),
    key: (item) => DateTime.utc(2020, 10, item * 5),
    value: (item) => List.generate(
        item % 4 + 1, (index) => calEvent('Event $item | ${index + 1}')))
  ..addAll({
    DateTime.now(): [
      calEvent('Today\'s Event 1'),
      calEvent('Today\'s Event 2'),
    ],
  });

int getHashCode(DateTime key) {
  return key.day * 1000000 + key.month * 10000 + key.year;
}

/// Returns a list of [DateTime] objects from [first] to [last], inclusive.
List<DateTime> daysInRange(DateTime first, DateTime last) {
  final dayCount = last.difference(first).inDays + 1;
  return List.generate(
    dayCount,
        (index) => DateTime.utc(first.year, first.month, first.day + index),
  );
}

final kNow = DateTime.now();
final kFirstDay = DateTime(kNow.year, kNow.month - 3, kNow.day);
final kLastDay = DateTime(kNow.year, kNow.month + 3, kNow.day);
```

I create events on another page and store them in a Firebase collection. I can pull those events from the collection into a Stream<DateTime, List> but then I want to display them on the table_calendar grid based on the day they should occur. This code does this very well but not from a firebase collection. I want to implement it into my code but use code for pulling events from the Firebase collection as the source.

My problem is that I don't understand how/where to put my code in the _kEventSource code. I am attaching a file with some of my code so you can see what I am doing.

I would greatly appreciate advice on this.

Here is the code for building the table_calendar:

This is the code that builds the basic calendar framework and builds the event list below the calendar grid.

```
class _AppointmentCalendarScreenState extends State<AppointmentCalendarScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final ValueNotifier<List<calEvent>> _selectedEvents;
  late StreamController<Map<DateTime, List>> _streamController;
  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
  RangeSelectionMode _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode
      .toggledOff; // Can be toggled on/off by longpressing a date
    
  List<calEvent> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    // Implementation example
    return kEvents[day] ?? [];
  }

  List<calEvent> _getEventsForRange(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    // Implementation example
    final days = daysInRange(start, end);

    return [
      for (final d in days) ..._getEventsForDay(d),
    ];
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
    if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
        _rangeStart = null; // Important to clean those
        _rangeEnd = null;
        _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOff;
      });

      _selectedEvents.value = _getEventsForDay(selectedDay);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final eventProvider = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context);
    FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/Appbar_logo.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder( **<<<<  I get the events from Firebase here**
            stream: **_firestoreService.getEventStream(_selectedDay)**,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot <List<Event>> eventsSnapShot) {
              if (eventsSnapShot.hasData) {
                var doc = eventsSnapShot.data!;
                for (int i = 0; i < doc.length; i++ ) {
                }
                return _buildTableCalendar();
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),

          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }

   **This is where the calendar grid is built**
  Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
    return TableCalendar(
      firstDay: kFirstDay,
      lastDay: kLastDay,
      focusedDay: _selectedDay,
      selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(_selectedDay, day),
      locale: 'en_US',
      eventLoader: _getEventsForDay, // **This is important**
      //holidays: _holidays,
      
      ),

      onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
      //onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
      //onCalendarCreated: _onCalendarCreated,
      
    );
  }
```

This is the code for the call, FirestoreService().getEvent(), I use to get the events from the Firebase collection:

```
Stream<List<Event>> getEventStream(DateTime dateTime) async* {
    yield* _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).collection('event')
        .where('eventDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime))
        .snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => Event.fromFirestore(document.data()))
        .toList());
  }
```

This is the Event data model:

```
class Event {
  final String? eventName;
  //final TimeOfDay eventStartTime;
  final DateTime? eventStartTime;
  final String? eventDuration;
  final DateTime? eventDate;
  final String? eventDescription;
  final String? agentId;
  final String? agencyId;


  Event(
      {this.eventName,
      this.eventStartTime,
      this.eventDuration,
      this.eventDate,
      this.eventDescription,
      this.agentId,
      this.agencyId});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'eventName': eventName,
      'eventStartTime': eventStartTime,
      'eventDuration': eventDuration,
      'eventDate': eventDate,
      'eventDescription': eventDescription,
      'agentId': agentId,
      'agencyId': agencyId,
    };
  }

  // pass in a map and get an object back
  Event.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : eventName = firestore['eventName'],
        eventStartTime = firestore['eventStartTime'].toDate(),
        eventDuration = firestore['eventDuration'],
        eventDate = firestore['eventDate'].toDate(),
        eventDescription = firestore['eventDescription'],
        agentId = firestore['agentId'],
        agencyId = firestore['agencyId'];
}
```

Comment: The second code snippet you've pasted is too long. Can you only show the relevant part?

Comment: @Nicks101 I cut a lot of the unnecessary code from the second snippet. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before `kEvents`, you have to make another `map`.
These are the steps with code snippets.

- Get data from firebase (`List<Event>`)
  You are already doing this.
  Let's called this `snapshot.data`
- Map these events to `kEventSource`.

```dart
 Map<DateTime, List<Event>> kEventSource = {};

    (snapshot.data).forEach((element) {
      kEventSource[DateTime(  
        element.time.year,
        element.time.month,
        element.time.day,
      )] = kEventSource[DateTime(
                element.time.year,
                element.time.month,
                element.time.day,
              )] !=
              null
          ? [
              ...kEventSource[DateTime(
                element.time.year,
                element.time.month,
                element.time.day,
              )],
              element
            ]
          : [element];
    });
```

Now we have a map data structure with `dateTime` as key and list of events on that day as value.
Example:

```dart
{
  "2 July 2021" : [Event1, Event2, ...],
  ...
}
```

- Now `kEvents` is defined.

```dart
final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>(
      equals: isSameDay,
      hashCode: getHashCode,
    )..addAll(kEventSource);
```

`isSameDay` functions come from the package itself.
Source code:

```dart
/// Checks if two DateTime objects are the same day.
/// Returns `false` if either of them is null.
bool isSameDay(DateTime? a, DateTime? b) {
  if (a == null || b == null) {
    return false;
  }

  return a.year == b.year && a.month == b.month && a.day == b.day;
}
```

Same for `getHashCode`. Though you can modify it.
Source Code:

```dart
  int getHashCode(DateTime key) {
    return key.day * 1000000 + key.month * 10000 + key.year;
  }
```

Now you have the `KEvents`, so you can use others features like selecting in range, etc.

Refernce: [table_calender](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/events_example.dart)

I'll encourage you to look at the examples provided by the package author.

Comment: What do the dots mean:               ...kEventSource[DateTime(

Comment: It's a [spreading operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator). It means to open the list and show individual items in it. So here it's saying, if there are already some Events for the same date, add them too.

Comment: Thanks for that. I looked it up but your explanation was better. If you don't mind I will post my code once I get it together and ask your opinion. I am new to flutter/Dart and firebase but I am learning.

Comment: This might not the best platform for code review. Try looking for other places, like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199680/whats-acceptable-practice-for-stack-overflow-code-review-for-several-source-fil) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Hey @nicks101, thanks for providing the answer. However due to the fact I am new to dart/flutter I don't see what's the best way to integrate what you defined 'snapshot.data' with the method exposed by the author of the post. In your example you are using the variable kEventSource, but can you explain how to avoid that and interact directly with a method that returns List<Event> that invokes getEventStream? thanks

Comment: The `kEventSource` is independent of the backend you use. Doesn't matter how and where you get the data, you just have to map it to `kEventSource`. The `snapshot.data` can be anything (stream in your case). From what I understand, reading about "mapping firebase stream events into UI in flutter" might help you.

Comment: Thanks nicks101, my feeling is that my little experience with the topic does not help. I will try to read more, however my point was connected to the fact that I know via a StreamBuilder or a FutureBuilder you can fetch the data and when ready you can map it to the events so the current month's events can be showed; however it's still unclear to me how to correctly fetch "new data" when a page is changed (month) as it's an asynchronous call (again). So the only solution I can think about is to read 6 months and keep it, but I don't really like it. I will read more to understand better.

Comment: You can fetch data when the user changes a page or at any other trigger, with the required parameters.
The code for apping the data to UI however remains the same.